# Migrating to Magento 2 "crypt_key" option is not defined the configuration

Tags: magento2, migration

When Running the transfer tool I get the error "crypt_key" option has not defined the configuration.

This is from local.xml on the old site

```
<crypt>
        <key><![CDATA[adfabde1a4e1533ec61eae16e58abb66]]></key>
    </crypt>
```

Here is the xml.config

```
<options>

<crypt_key>adfabde1a4e1533ec61eae16e58abb66</crypt_key>
```

Anyone have an idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

There is another `<crypt_key>` tab at the bottom of this file. You need to delete this tab.